# in Ruby on Rails 2.3.2, how to print out params during a create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

there is a scaffold created Story... and in the create action, there is

```
@story = Story.new(params[:story])
```

i was curious as to what is in params... so i want to dump out params... but there is no view associated with the create action...  is there a way to dump out its content?  is there a way to dump out the POST variables in of my code too?  (to see what's going on in the lower level)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is just dump params out to the log:

```
Rails.logger.info("PARAMS: #{params.inspect}")
```

If you're in development mode, just look in your development.log and that line will be there.

The params scope is a combination of URL/FORM (GET/POST) fields, and it will be printed out in the log as part of the normal output processing, so you might not need your own dumping of it - any development or production log contains the params dump at the top of the log line, e.g.

```
Processing Clients::ClientsController#show (for x.x.x. at 2009-05-24 00:34:26) [GET]
  Parameters: {"id"=>"303", "user_id"=>"2"}
```

Comment: Is this regardless of the log_level?

Comment: @willem obst - no, you're right, this will only print out when the log level is info or lower. You can use Rails.logger.debug to print it out in either development or production.

Answer (score 2):

Now I know Rails more, you can also simply use a

```
p params
```

in your code and look at the console's output (the log shown on the console)

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac, [Spike](http://github.com/mmower/spike/tree/master) is a great little app the analyses log files and will let you inspect params for requests, amongst other things.

Answer (score 1):

Using Fiddler on Windows, it is shown

the HTTP line #1 is:

```
POST /stories HTTP/1.1
```

this is the POST content:

> authenticity_token=62iw%2BrsxlCFsbnxsS7FXKRn6CcvJfjottrsBPlM5lZo%3D&story%5Bname%5D=Google+Main+Site&story%5Blink%5D=www.google.com&commit=Create

listed in a table:

```
authenticity_token  62iw+rsxlCFsbnxsS7FXKRn6CcvJfjottrsBPlM5lZo=
story[name]         Google Main Site
story[link]         www.google.com
commit              Create
```

and the server log is:

> Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create", "story"=>{"name"=>"Google Main Site", "link"=>"www.google.com"}, "authenticity_token"=>"62iw+rsxlCFsbnxsS7FXKRn6CcvJfjottrsBPlM5lZo="}

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to anything except look in your logs (they live in `/log`).  Unless you're fiddling with something, the logging of parameters is turned on by default in all logs.

```
Processing PostsController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-05-24 13:03:24) [POST]
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create", "authenticity_token"=>"2G6BKOs8xNAaXiToVf4r1ko8QZzP9QAomi2PHVQC5Oc=", "story"=>{"something"=>"asdfafd"}}
```

`Parameters` lists all parameters, and the hash following `"story"` is the equivalent of `params[:story]` (everything comes to the server as strings, and Rails turns it into a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` so that you can access it with a symbol).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a *NIX system (including OS X) open a new terminal window/tab and type the following command:

tail -f log/development.log

You'll get a constant stream of requests coming in -- including params -- and the resulting DB actions.  Invaluable for development/debugging, IMO.